# h(n) selection in A* algorithm for 2x2 rubik's cube solving

Tags: a-star, rubiks-cube

I am currently working on a 2x2 Rubik's cube solving robot project. It takes in the cube data via a 2x2 color sensor array and solves it using some servo motors and arms. I was looking on wiki and I think A* would be a possible way to write the program to solve it. However, I can't figure out how to define the expected cost function(h) for the cube. It isn't finding the shortest path on a 2D plane, where h(n) can simply be some form of actual distance(Euclidean, Manhattan, etc). I was originally thinking about counting how many tiles have already grouped up, but it won't really work since I can just do 2~3 moves on the cube and many tiles are disconnected. How exactly should I write this cost function? Or is there a better alternative to A* in my case? (2x2 is too simple to use IDA*, I guess. The max possible move count to solve it is only 11)

Answer (score 2):

A* with iterative-deepening, depth-first search (IDA*) is a good way to go.  For the heuristic, define one or more pattern databases, where each key is a cube state, and each value is the distance to the solved state from that cube state.  To keep the databases reasonably small, each database can hold a subset of the cube's overall state.  Regarding the heuristic, given a cube state, look up the distance in every database.  The maximum of those distances is the best estimated distance to the solved state (i.e. it takes *at least* that many moves to solve the cube).

For example, one could make a database that has the orientations of all 8 cubies.  Just the orientations mind you, not the positions.  Since each piece can be in one of three orientations--on the top layer, any sticker can point up, for example--there are 3^8 possible states.  I'm not an expert in the 2x2, but I'm pretty sure that it's impossible to disorient just one piece.  That is, it's not possible to have a solved 2x2 and then flip just one cubie.  Assuming that's correct, there are actually 3^7=2187 possible orientation states.  You would then iterate using BFS from the solved state and find each of these 2187 states, encode each state into an integer from 0-2186, and store the distance from that state to the solved state.  Put another way, a database is just a hash table.

You could make multiple databases in the same manner.  For example, the positions of the 8 pieces.  The positions and orientations of 4 of the 8 pieces.  Etc.

When it comes time to solve the cube, use IDA*.  Each time a state is encountered, check the maximum distance provided from all of the pattern databases.  There's your heuristic function.  Prune accordingly.

I have [an article on Medium](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/implementing-an-optimal-rubiks-cube-solver-using-korf-s-algorithm-bf750b332cf9?sk=bf4d6a245e07e37dc94d84e77489ffc6) that goes into a lot more detail, but it's for the 3x3.  The same strategy works, though.

P.s. The 2x2 is small enough that one can make a perfect pattern database with the exact distance from each state to the solved state and store that database on disk in only 1.8MB.  (There are 3,674,160 states, with a God's number of 11.  11 can fit in a nibble.  3,674,160/1024^2/2 ~= 1.8MB.) With that database, IDA* would be able to solve the 2x2 effectively instantaneously.

Comment: But a database-based algorithm would probably not runable on an Arduino. There simply isn't enough memory space. Or is there a way to take this load away from the arduino, like an external memory perhaps? But that would be very complicated.

Comment: For a complete database you would need about 1.8MB of storage, so an SD card or other Arduino-compatible storage would be needed.  Obviously you couldn't load the entire DB into memory, but that's not necessarily a requirement for the algorithm.  Also, I mentioned upfront using smaller databases: you could use a handful of small databases that can fit in memory, and use the max entry of those as a heuristic.  The one I mentioned specifically would only require 2187/2 bytes.